# How to make ExpressionEngine site Responsive

Tags: responsive-images

Our EE is of v2.5.3 - Build Date: 20120911 and we are trying to make it Responsive. How we can do it?

Thanks.
Regards,
Roshan

Answer (score 2):

EE separates the content of your site from its design - the pages that appear on your user device are generated via templates that mix HTML coding instructions with special tags that cause content to be pulled from the EE database into the HTML templates.  This clean separation is one of the things that makes EE a very powerful CMS.

As a result, getting EE to be Responsive is simply a question of building a set of page templates that are themselves Responsive.  Any approach that works can be applied through EE - so you can build templates using responsive frameworks such as Foundation or Bootstrap, or roll your own.

Simple responsive designs based on Foundation or Bootstrap etc. work by making local adjustments to the CSS on the page based on the size of the viewport - in the most extreme case hiding content (e.g. by not showing some page elements on smaller devices, or downloading multiple versions and choosing which one to show based on viewport size etc.).  But all this happens in the browser - not in the server.

If you want an easy way to get started, google around for a simple free responsive HTML template, load it up in EE and put some EE tags in to populate content and see how it goes.  As you get the hang of it you'll work out how to make best use of EE resources to get the responsive features working well.

HTH